# Insert names in a database Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I need to create a list of names to display in my MainActivity. This list will be dynamic so I have to use a database. I've never used the db on Android so I need your help; What I've to do it's something like this: 
I have a `+` button to add the names. I'll display a dialog with `"insert the name: "edit_text_where_put_the_name"` and an `ok` button will confirm the insert. Then the added name will be visible in the Activity. How can I do something like this? There is anyone who has an example (code) or an idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to first learn how to use databases (they aren't that scary once you get into it). Then check out the popular embeddable databases - SQLite is a pretty popular one, but my personal favorite is H2 Database (I find it behaves more like a normal RDMS such as mysql over the sometimes-quite-different SQLite syntax). I don't know what Android allows you to use, but I'd wager any of the embeddable ones will do, however it's noteworthy that I've seen SQLite be used more commonly.

Comment: and here's your link: http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#android

Comment: You're right! I use mysql normally but never use sqlLite or database in general on Android. I'll take a look. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Android SQLite database and content provider - tutorial  Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)